# How to Enable Multi Language Capability in CodeIgniter JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a multi language web with CodeIgniter. I am just a beginner and I know some method after googling. I have success implementing multi language by following [this guide](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/multi-language-codeigniter/).

It's easy to implement on PHP files, but I have a problem. How to implement multi language on a JavaScript files?

I've found [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/j88iog/internationalized-javascript-files-in-codeigniter), but I can't implement it.

I can't implement:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('jsloader/my_javascript_file.js" />
```

Because the web I develop has template directory, and the js file currently called with this (in `footer.php`):

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory(dirname(__FILE__), 'js/') ;?>my_javascript_file.js"></script>
```

So, how to internationalize the js file in these template directory?

Comment: Since you are calling `get_template_directory()` method, why not just parse the text in there too? what I'm saying is you could return the parsed js text too instead of just the path

Comment: why do you want to use different js file?

Comment: why not use language helper

Comment: @HastaDhana I am not sure about your question, the js file is related to the template

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin I just only one file js at the template directory

Comment: why do you want to implement multi language on a JavaScript?

Comment: Do you have a different script for every language?

Comment: Do you have access to the helper that contains the `get_template_directory()` method? It doesn't matter where the js file is, you could just pass the js filename as a parameter to that method and that method will return the translated version